# StyledCellLabelProvider Does Not Know SWT.BOLD Nor SWT.ITALIC

Tags: java, jface

I have a pretty standard `StyledCellLabelProvider`, yet when I set the `StyleRanges` neither `SWT.BOLD` nor `SWT.ITALIC` are recognized (even though JavaDoc states both are valid values). Yet underline is rendered correctly.

I tried setting the object `StyleRange#font`, too, but to no avail.

Comprehensive example:

```
public class BoldStyledCellExample extends ApplicationWindow {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final BoldStyledCellExample example = new BoldStyledCellExample();
        example.setBlockOnOpen(true);
        example.open();
    }

    public BoldStyledCellExample() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createContents(final Composite parent) {
        final TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        final TableViewerColumn column1 = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEFT);
        column1.getColumn().setText("Foo");
        column1.getColumn().setWidth(250);
        column1.setLabelProvider(new StyledCellLabelProvider() {

            @Override
            public void update(final ViewerCell cell) {
                final String letter = (String) cell.getElement();

                cell.setText(letter);
                cell.setStyleRanges(new StyleRange[] { new StyleRange(0, letter.length(), null, null, SWT.ITALIC) });
                super.update(cell);
            }
        });

        viewer.setInput(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
        return viewer.getTable();
    }
}
```

Since this might just be a OS problem, I'm using Eclipse 3.7 (but it doesn't work with 4.5 either) and Win10.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug [350041](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350041) which currently has no fix. This bug is a duplicate of the much older bug [131988](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=131988)